# TCL String Manipulation and Extraction

Tags: tcl

I have a string `xxxxxxx-s12345ab7_0_0_xx2.log` and need to have an output like `AB700_xx2` in TCL.

`ab` will be the delimiter and need to extract from `ab` to `.` (including `ab`) and also have to remove only the first two underscores.

Tried `string trim`, `string trimleft` and `string trimright`, but not much use. Is there anything like `string split` in TCL?

Comment: Can you explain the structure of the string? Is the `ab` delimiter always the same? Are the *7*, *0*, *0* always single digits? Is the *x* an *any character* placeholder?

Comment: `string trim*` isn't the right tool for this job, and `string split` is just called `split`…

Answer (score 4):

The first stage is to extract the basic relevant substring; the easiest way to do that is actually with a regular expression:

```
set inputString "xxxxxxx-s12345ab7_0_0_xx2.log"

if {![regexp {ab[^.]+} $inputString extracted]} {
    error "didn't match!"
}
puts "got $extracted"
# ===> got ab7_0_0_xx2
```

Then, we want to get rid of those nasty underscores with `string map`:

```
set final [string map {"_" ""} $extracted]
puts "got $final"
# ===> ab700xx2
```

Hmm, not quite what we wanted! We wanted to keep the last underscore and to up-case the first part.

```
set pieces [split $extracted "_"]
set final [string toupper [join [lrange $pieces 0 2] ""]]_[join [lrange $pieces 3 end] "_"]
puts "got $final"
# ===> got AB700_xx2
```

(The `split` command divides a string up into “records” by an optional record specifier — which defaults to any whitespace character — that we can then manipulate easily with list operations. The `join` command does the reverse, but here I'm using an empty record specifier on one half which makes everything be concatenated. I think you can guess what the `string toupper` and `lrange` commands do…)

Comment: I would do `regsub -all {_(\d)} $extracted {\1} final` to remove the "inner" underscores, give or take unspoken requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
set a "xxxxxxx-s12345ab7_0_0_xx2.log"
set a [split $a ""]
set trig 0
set extract ""
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $a]} {incr i} {
    if {"ab" eq "[lindex $a $i][lindex $a [expr $i+1]]"} {
        set trig 1
    }
    if {$trig == 1} {
        append extract [lindex $a $i]
    }
}

set extract "[string toupper [join [lrange [split [lindex [split $extract .] 0] _] 0 end-1] ""]]_[lindex [split [lindex [split $extract .] 0] _] end]"

puts $extract
```

Answer (score 0):

Only regexp is enough to do the trick.

Set string `"xxxxxxx-s12345ab7_0_0_xx2.log"`

```
regexp {(ab)(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\\.} $string -> s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
```

Set rstring `"$s1$s2$s3$s4\_$s5"`

Puts `$rstring`